# pySpark to update datetime stamp without converting to local time

Tags: pyspark

In pySpark need to convert forex trading date time as everyday 16pm as day+1, so I did below code and works well, however when I tried to truncate hour/minute/second and keep up to date only, no matter what I do system always converts to Sydney time (I am in Sydney Australia).

I searched google and know I need to set spark session to GMT, however I am using a system called Palantir, it is different from normal pySpark code editor, when I dump code  `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")` it always gave me error. Is there anyway can round to day in London zone without setting spark timezone? Thank you

```
.withColumn('test_trade_date', F.from_utc_timestamp(F.from_unixtime(F.unix_timestamp(F.col('trade_date_time'))+8*60*60), 'LONDON'))\
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `pandas_udf` to convert the datetime to whatever timezone you want.